# How to prove $\mathbb{E}\{M_m 1_{\Psi}\}=\mathbb{E}\{M_n1_{\Psi}\}$, given that $n\geq m$, $\Psi\in\mathcal{F_m}$ and $(M_n)_{n\geq1}$ is martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, expected-value, martingales

Given a probability space $(\Omega$, $\mathcal{F}$, $\mathbb{P})$, $(M_n)_{n\geq1}$ is a martingale. Let $\Psi \in \mathcal{F}_m$ and $n\geq m$. How can one prove that, by martingale property
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\{M_n1_{\Psi}\}=E\{M_m1_{\Psi}\}
\end{equation}
?

---

I was thinking about focusing on r.h.s. of the above equation. By martingale property, one would have
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\{M_m1_{\Psi}\}=\mathbb{E}\{\mathbb{E}\{M_n|\mathcal{F_m}\}1_{\Psi}\}
\end{equation}
However, at this point, giving that the outer expectation is defined on the product $\mathbb{E}\{M_n|\mathcal{F}_m\}1_{\Psi}$ I am not sure I am allowed to apply the Law of Iterated Expectations on $\mathbb{E}\{\mathbb{E}\{M_n|\mathcal{F_m}\}\}$ so as to conclude that, given that $\mathbb{E}\{\mathbb{E}\{M_n|\mathcal{F_m}\}\}=M_n$, it holds true that:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\{M_m1_{\Psi}\}=\mathbb{E}\{\mathbb{E}\{M_n|\mathcal{F_m}\}1_{\Psi}\}=\mathbb{E}\{M_n 1_{\Psi}\}
\end{equation}

*Am I actually allowed to do so?*

Comment: If $g$ is an $\mathcal{F}_m$ measurable function then $$\mathbb{E}[fg \mid \mathcal{F}_m] = g \mathbb{E}[f \mid \mathcal{F}_m].$$

Comment: "By martingale property, one would have  : ..." is correct. However, by the definition of conditional expectation and the fact that $\Psi \in \mathcal F_m$, the RHS of that equation is equal to $\mathbb E[M_n 1_{\Psi}]$, so we get the result without any law of iterated expectations, but by merely applying the definition of conditional expectation to a specific set. (Even the law of iterated expectations is a special case of the conditional expectation definition with the set taken as the whole space.)

Comment: I guess you mean that I can show that l.h.s=r.h.s. by simply conditioning both r.h.s expectation and l.h.s. expectation with respect to $\mathcal{F_m}$. This is already ok. Anyway, could there be another strategy to show that r.h.s=l.h.s.? Just for the sake of curiosity @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: @Strictly_increasing There could be, but I can't think of one. Anyway, +1.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thank you :)

Comment: I guess you mean that I can show that l.h.s=r.h.s. by simply conditioning both r.h.s expectation and l.h.s. expectation with respect to Fm. This is already ok. Anyway, could there be another strategy to show that r.h.s=l.h.s.? Just for the sake of curiosity @RhysSteele

Comment: @Strictly_increasing I meant that since $1_\Psi$ is $\mathcal{F}_m$ measurable, $$\mathbb{E}[M_m 1_\Psi] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[M_n | \mathcal{F}_m] 1_\Psi] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[M_n 1_\Psi | \mathcal{F}_m] ] = \mathbb{E}[M_n 1_\Psi]$$. This is a completion of the start of your argument and just transforms the RHS into the LHS

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time and help!!!

Comment: Pardon @RhysSteele, just one last observation/request. I am pretty sure that $(M_n)_{n\geq1}$ is a martingale IFF $\mathbb{E}\{M_n1_{\Psi}\}=\mathbb{E}\{M_m1_{\Psi}\}$, that is...NOT ONLY "$(M_n)_{n\geq0}$ is a martingale" $\Rightarrow \mathbb{E}\{M_n1_{\Psi}\}=\mathbb{E}\{M_m1_{\Psi}\}$ BUT ALSO $\mathbb{E}\{M_n1_{\Psi}\}=\mathbb{E}\{M_m1_{\Psi}\} \Rightarrow$ "$(M_n)_{n\geq0}$ is a martingale" holds true. And so as to prove the other direction I think it suffices to condition both r.h.s. and l.h.s. of $\mathbb{E}\{M_n1_{\Psi}\}=\mathbb{E}\{M_m1_{\Psi}\}$ wrt $\mathcal{F_m}$. Am I right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by condition both sides wrt $\mathcal{F}_m$ since both sides are constant. It is right that if $(M_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is an adapted sequence of integrable random variable such that for every $n \geq m$ and every $\Psi \in \mathcal{F}_m$ you have
$$\mathbb{E}\{M_n1_{\Psi}\}=\mathbb{E}\{M_m1_{\Psi}\}$$
then $(M_n)$ is a martingale. This is because the assumed condition just says $M_m = \mathbb{E}[M_n | \mathcal{F}_m]$ by the definition of conditional expectation (It is just the definition written out for the $\mathcal{F}_m$ measurable random variable $M_m$).

Comment: @RhysSteele I mean that, not knowing ex-ante that $(M_n)_{n\geq1}$ is a martingale, starting from
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\{M_n1_{\Psi}\}=\mathbb{E}\{M_m1_{\Psi}\}
\end{equation}
if one 'conditions' the 'content' of expectation wrt $\mathcal{F_m}$, that is
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\{M_n1_{\Psi}|\mathcal{F_m}\}=\mathbb{E}\{M_m1_{\Psi}|\mathcal{F_m}\}
\end{equation}
by measurability of $M_m$ and $\Psi$ wrt $\mathcal{F}_m$, one gets
\begin{equation}
1_{\Psi}\mathbb{E}\{M_n|\mathcal{F}_m\}=1_{\Psi}M_m
\end{equation}
that is, by definition, $(M_n)_{n\geq1}$ is a martingale

Comment: You can't just replace an expectation with a conditional expectation in general. Equal expectation does not imply equal conditional expectation. To get a counterexample, notice you only use the case $\Psi = \Omega$ so then the claim is that $\mathbb{E}[M_n] = \mathbb{E}[M_m]$ implies equality of the conditional expectations. Let $M_n, M_m$ be i.i.d. mean zero random variables. The expectations are equal but 
$$M_m = \mathbb{E}[M_m | \sigma(M_m)] \neq \mathbb{E}[M_n] = \mathbb{E}[M_n | \sigma(M_m)].$$

Comment: Thank you a lot for clarifying this with a very clear counterexample, I got it @RhysSteele